# how to extend the start up time for a scylla node if it is loading data

Tags: scylla

getting this error during startup time of scylla node as I am loading data

```
Nov 12 21:55:13 usw1-im-stage-scylladb1 scylla[53703]:  [shard 0] database - Keyspace product_prod: Reading CF cleanup_transaction id=bb0a0640-058f-11ea-b8e4-00000000000c version=dde3ee6f-185b-37ba-80fb-6425cce4532f

Nov 12 22:10:02 usw1-im-stage-scylladb1 systemd[1]: scylla-server.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
```

running this on scylla enterprise 2019.1.2

Answer (score 5):

Scylla's documentation includes KBs and FAQ. I think this KB is **spot-on**, what you are looking for:
https://docs.scylladb.com/troubleshooting/scylla_wont_start/#solution

Here is the solution suggested there:

1. Locate the directory with the systemd files where the scylla-server.service resides.

   - For Centos operating systems it is expected to be under `/usr/lib/systemd/system/scylla-server.service`
   - For Ubuntu operating systems it is expected to be under `/etc/systemd/system/scylla-server.service.d`
2. Create the following directory (if not exist)

   - Centos
     `sudo mkdir /usr/lib/systemd/system/scylla-server.service`
   - Ubuntu
     `sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/scylla-server.service.d`
3. Create a file inside that directory named `10-timeout.conf`, with the following contents:

```
[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=9000​
```

4. Reload the systemd Daemon for the new configurations to take in effect.

`systemctl daemon-reload`

Comment: Is `TimeoutStartSec=9000​` specified in seconds?  so systemd will wait for 2.5 hrs before timing out and killing the scylla process?

Comment: Yes @Mahee Gunturu, it's in Sec, and Yes, Systemd will wait for the specified time (seconds) before terminating Scylla process on TimeOut.